# Recursive algorithm for cos taylor series expansion c++

Tags: c++, math, recursion, trigonometry

I recently wrote a Computer Science exam where they asked us to give a recursive definition for the cos taylor series expansion. This is the series

cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! + x^6/6! ...

and the function signature looks as follows

```
float cos(int n , float x)
```

where n represents the number in the series the user would like to calculate till and x represents the value of x in the cos function

I obviously did not get that question correct and I have been trying to figure it out for the past few days but I have hit a brick wall

Would anyone be able to help out getting me started somewhere ?

Comment: If you must have a recursive definition, then rewrite `1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6! + ...` as `1 - (x^2/2)(1 - (x^2/(3*4))(1 - (x^2/(5*6))(1 - ...)))`.

Comment: I suggest you don't use recursion for evaluating a Taylor series.  Most programs are given a limited amount of space for recursion.  You will probably exhaust the limits; the question is for which limit.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'd be very surprised if he exhausted the limit on the stack; it's not necessary to evaluate very many members of the series to get accurate results.  (On the other hand, there's really no reason to use recursion here; a simple loop would be just as good, and probably faster.)

Answer (score 7):

All answers so far recompute the factorial every time. I surely wouldn't do that. Instead you can write :

```
float cos(int n, float x)
{
    if (n > MAX)
         return 1;
    return 1 - x*x / ((2 * n - 1) * (2 * n)) * cos(n + 1, x);
}
```

Consider that cos returns the following (sorry for the dots position) :

[image: cos function formula]

You can see that this is true for n>MAX, n=MAX, and so on. The sign alternating and powers of x are easy to see.

Finally, at n=1 you get 0! = 1, so calling `cos(1, x)` gets you the first MAX terms of the Taylor expansion of cos.

By developing (easier to see when it has few terms), you can see the first formula is equivalent to the following :

[image: reformulation cos formula]

For n > 0, you do in cos(n-1, x) a division by (2n-3)(2n-2) of the previous result, and a multiplication by x². You can see that when n=MAX+1 this formula is 1, with n=MAX then it is `1-x²/((2MAX-1)2MAX)` and so on.

If you allow yourself helper functions, then you should change the signature of the above to `float cos_helper(int n, float x, int MAX)` and call it like so :

`float cos(int n, float x) { return cos_helper(1, x, n); }`

---

Edit : To reverse the meaning of `n` from degree of the evaluated term (as in this answer so far) to number of terms (as in the question, and below), but still not recompute the total factorial every time, I would suggest using a two-term relation.

Let us define trivially `cos(0,x) = 0` and `cos(1,x) = 1`, and try to achieve generally cos(n,x) the sum of the n first terms of the Taylor series.

Then for each n > 0, we can write, cos(n,x) from cos(n-1,x) :

> cos(n,x) = cos(n-1,x) + x<sup>2n</sup> / (2n)!

now for n > 1, we try to make the last term of cos(n-1,x) appear (because it is the closest term to the one we want to add) :

> cos(n,x) = cos(n-1,x) + x² / ((2n-1)2n) * ( x<sup>2n-2</sup> / (2n-2)! )

By combining this formula with the previous one (adapting it to n-1 instead of n) :

> cos(n,x) = cos(n-1,x) + x² / ((2n-1)2n) * ( cos(n-1,x) - cos(n-2,x) )

We now have a purely recursive definition of cos(n,x), without helper function, without recomputing the factorial, and with n the number of terms in the sum of the Taylor decomposition.

**However, I must stress that the following code will perform terribly :**

- **performance wise, unless some optimization allows to not re-evaluate a `cos(n-1,x)` that was evaluated at the previous step as `cos( (n-1) - 1, x)`**
- **precision wise, because of cancellation effects : the precision with which we get x<sup>2n-2</sup> / (2n-2)! is very bad**

Now this disclaimer is in place, here comes the code :

```
float cos(int n, float x)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    float c = x * x / (2 * (n - 1) * 2 * n);
    return (1-c) * cos(n-1, x) + c * cos(n-2, x);
}
```

Comment: This is in the right direction but, from the question, "n represents the number in the series the user would like to calculate till".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well spotted. I updated the answer to take that into account. It should do exactly what's described in the question now, but i wouldn't trust its results.

Comment: Just use a helper function for (and with the content of) the first approach, cos_helper(m,n,x) where m=MAX and cos(n,x) {return cos_helper(n,1,x);}

Comment: Well if you can use helper functions, then you can do anything anyway no ? I'm not sure what the limits of the question are exactly. @KeatonPennels ?

Answer (score 1):

```
cos(x)=1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6! + x^8/8!.....
=1-x^2/2 (1 - x^2/3*4 + x^4/3*4*5*6 -x^6/3*4*5*6*7*8)
=1 - x^2/2 {1- x^2/3*4 (1- x^2/5*6 + x^4/5*6*7*8)}
=1 - x^2/2 [1- x^2/3*4 {1- x^2/5*6 ( 1- x^2/7*8)}]

    double cos_series_recursion(double x, int n, double r=1){

        if(n>0){

            r=1-((x*x*r)/(n*(n-1)));

            return cos_series_recursion(x,n-2,r);
         }else return r;
    }
```

Comment: I agree static is not a good option here. I changed it to an optional parameter now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach that makes use of static variables:

```
double cos(double x, int n) {
    static double p = 1, f = 1;
    double r;

    if(n == 0)
        return 1;

    r = cos(x, n-1);
    p = (p*x)*x;
    f = f*(2*n-1)*2*n;

    if(n%2==0) {
        return r+p/f;
    } else {
        return r-p/f;
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm multiplying `2*n` in the operation to get the next factorial.
Having `n` align to the factorial we need makes this easy to do in 2 operations: `f = f * (n - 1)` then `f = f * n`.

```
when n = 1, we need 2!  
when n = 2, we need 4!  
when n = 3, we need 6!
```

So we can safely double `n` and work from there. We could write:
`n = 2*n;`
`f = f*(n-1);`
`f = f*n;`

If we did this, we would need to update our even/odd check to `if((n/2)%2==0)` since we're doubling the value of `n`.

This can instead be written as `f = f*(2*n-1)*2*n;` and now we don't have to divide `n` when checking if it's even/odd, since `n` is not being altered.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like the sum.

[image: cos]

The parameter `n` in `float cos(int n , float x)` is the `l` and now just do it...
Some pseudocode:

```
float cos(int n , float x)
{
                //the sum-part
    float sum = pow(-1, n) * (pow(x, 2*n))/faculty(2*n);

    if(n <= /*Some predefined maximum*/)
        return sum + cos(n + 1, x);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the test for the recursion be `if ( n >= 0 )`?

Comment: What do you mean by "test"? The abort condition? No. Look at the sum, it goes up to infinity and as we cannot really afford that, we'll just quit qfter some specified depth is reached.

Comment: This is in the right direction but, from the question, "n represents the number in the series the user would like to calculate till"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop or recursion, but I would recommend a loop. Anyway, if you must use recursion you could use something like the code below

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fact(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    else return n*fact(n-1);
}

float Cos(int n, float x) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return Cos(n-1, x) + (n%2 ? -1 : 1) * pow (x, 2*n) / (fact(2*n));
}

int main()
{
   cout << Cos(6, 3.14/6);

}
```

Comment: He doesn't have to use a recursive function for the factorial part, just the cos taylor series part. You could use a loop for the factorial which would be saner.

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique when you want to recurse but the function arguments don't carry the information that you need, is to introduce a ***helper function*** to do the recursion.

I have the impression that in the Lisp world the convention is to name such a function `something-`*`aux`* (short for *auxiliary*), but that may have been just a limited group in the old days.

Anyway, the main problem here is that `n` represents the natural ending point for the recursion, the base case, and that you then also need some index that works itself up to `n`. So, that's one good candidate for extra argument for the auxiliary function. Another candidate stems from considering how one term of the series relates to the previous one.

Comment: You can do it by counting down, but this would mean recalculating `x^(2*n)` and `(2*n)!` each time.  Otherwise, you probably need at least three additional values: a counter to compare to `n`, the running values of the powers of `x`, and the running values of the factorial.  (I'd probably create a class for this.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well you only need the running value for tail-recursion, I think. The OP didn't say anything about such requirement. But I agree, it's nicest. :)

Comment: Good point.  I don't know why I didn't think of it; I've used non-tail recursion in the past, so I'm aware that the possibility exists.